# Bank identification number validator

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm new to objective-c and I don't understand Java very well, my question:

I have this code in Java that verifies the Bank identification number:

```
 public static boolean isValidNIB(String nib) {
    char[] toValidate = nib.substring(0, 19).toCharArray();
    Integer checkDigit = Integer.valueOf(nib.substring(19));
    Integer[] wi = { 73, 17, 89, 38, 62, 45, 53, 15, 50, 5, 49, 34, 81, 76, 27, 90, 9, 30, 3 };
    Integer sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        sum += Character.digit(toValidate[i], 10) * wi[i];
    }
    return checkDigit.equals(98 - (sum % 97));
}
```

I need to convert this code into objective-c, the problem is that I can't make It work...

Here is my attempt to translate the java code into objective-c:

```
NSString *nib = @"003500970000199613031"; //UNICEF NIB :P

//transforms nsstring to array of chars
NSMutableArray *chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[nib length]];
for (int i=0; i < [nib length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [nib characterAtIndex:i]];
    [chars addObject:ichar];
}

NSLog(@"array nib = %@",chars);


//retrieves the first 19 chars
NSMutableArray *toValidate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i < chars.count; i++) {

    if (i <= 19) {
        [toValidate addObject:[chars objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"array toValidate = %@",toValidate);

NSString * checkDigit = [nib substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(19, 1)];


NSArray *weight = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"73", @"17", @"89", @"38", @"62", @"45", @"53", @"15", @"50", @"5", @"49", @"34", @"81", @"76", @"27", @"90", @"9", @"30", @"3", nil];



NSInteger sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < weight.count ; i++) {

    sum += [[toValidate objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] * [[weight objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];

}

if (checkDigit.integerValue == (98 -(sum % 97))) {
    NSLog(@"VALD");
}else{
    NSLog(@"NOT VALID");
}
```

I'm sure that this is not the correct approach but It's something.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you add the NSLog outputs, so its more easy to see where an error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one error. Your

```
NSString * checkDigit = [nib substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(19, 1)];
```

returns only one character (at position 19) from the identification number (in this case 
"3"), but

```
Integer checkDigit = Integer.valueOf(nib.substring(19));
```

computes the value of the substring *starting* at position 19 (in this case: "31").
Therefore the calculated checksum does not match the expected value.

But there is also a lot of unnecessary computations in your code, and there is 
no reason to store the weights in an array of strings.
The method can be shortened to:

```
NSString *nib = @"003500970000199613031";

int weight[] = { 73, 17, 89, 38, 62, 45, 53, 15, 50, 5, 49, 34, 81, 76, 27, 90, 9, 30, 3 };
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    sum += [[nib substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue] * weight[i];
}
int checkDigit = [[nib substringFromIndex:19] intValue];
if (checkDigit == (98 - (sum % 97))) {
    NSLog(@"VALID");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NOT VALID");
}
```

And the output is "VALID".